# How to checkout on branch having changes to a file which is skipped

Tags: git

My current branch is say `branch_a`

I have `local settings` file skipped using the following command.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file_local_settings>
```

Now I am pulling a branch from another developer from his repo, who has changed his version of `<file_local_settings>` and pushed to his repo.

I get the following error when I try to checkout to a branch created say `branch_b` from his branch after pulling.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

My question is what is the elegant way to checkout to `branch_b`?

Comment: The problem is abusing the index flag `skip-worktree` in this way.  This sort of problem is why I consistently warn against that practice, and recommend using the tools as designed instead.

Comment: So @MarkAdelsberger, does that mean we do not have an elegant solution for it?

Comment: There is no solution I consider elegant for tracking a file but ignoring changes to that file in git, no.  There *are* alternative solutions to most (if not all) of the underlying problems people try to solve by tracking a file but ignoring changes to it.  Mostly those involve more sophisticated build tooling.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I followed the steps in my answer below, It did work for me. Do you think, that is elegant enough to maintain the git's design flow?

Comment: If you find it sufficient to (1) have a checkout fail, (2) know (or have recorded) which files' index bits to modify, (3) perform a `reset` to avoid accidental checkin - meaning you're discarding any local changes you do have, (4) and hten reset the index bits...  Then go right ahead.  But do I think that's an elegant solution?  No.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I may not be understanding the significance of not using `skip-worktree`.

Comment: I think I spelled out my reasons for not liking your solution in my previous comment.  If you find that process suitable for you, then by all means go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so what I did is following.

1. `git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file_local_settings>`
2. Anyway I do not wanted to push my changes to `<file_local_settings>` I ran
3. `git reset --hard` #Be cautious or you could just do `git checkout <file_local_settings>`
4. git checkout `branch_b`
5. `git update-index --skip-worktree <file_local_settings>`